# Flutter : Get daily points system button error

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a function for users to get daily points (every 24 Hours). The function is linked with Firebase Firestore.

My problem is that if I close the app, relaunch it and click the triggering button ($checkPoints). It will add extra points to database even if the user did it less than 24 Hours ago !

Can you please check the code under and help me fix this?

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    class Authfirestore {
      final String uid;
      int points;
      var dateFromApitme;
      String lastTimeGotPointsFromFirebase;
      Authfirestore({this.uid, this.points});

      Firestore _firestore = Firestore();

      Future checkPoints() async {
        await dateApi();
        if (dateFromApitme != null ) {
          try {
            if (lastTimeGotPointsFromFirebase != dateFromApitme && dateFromApitme != null) {
              await getData();
              dynamic result = _firestore
                  .collection('users')
                  .document('Jm7bx8NOE9Nfx6P8S1wD')
                  .setData({
                'points': points + 1,
                'LastTimeGotPoints' :dateFromApitme,
              });
              await getData();
              print(result.toString());
              trackingData();
            } else {
              print('You toke your cridit ');
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error in cehckpoints $e');
          }
        }
      }

      Future trackingData() async {
        await Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document('Jm7bx8NOE9Nfx6P8S1wD')
            .collection('tracking')
            .document(_randomString(20))
            .setData({
          'date': DateTime.now(),
        });
      }

      Future getData() async {
        await Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document('Jm7bx8NOE9Nfx6P8S1wD')
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          points = ds.data['points'];
          lastTimeGotPointsFromFirebase = ds.data['LastTimeGotPoints'];
          print('number of points is $points');
        });

      }

      String _randomString(int length) {
        va

r rand = new Random();
    var codeUnits = new List.generate(length, (index) {
      return rand.nextInt(33) + 89;
    });

    return new String.fromCharCodes(codeUnits);
  }

  Future dateApi() async {
    var response =
        await http.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Muscat');
    if (response != null) {
      var data0 = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data01 = data0['datetime'];
      dateFromApitme = data01.substring(0, 9);
    } else {
      dateFromApitme = null;
      print('Please Check Your internet');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have the code to check if 24 hours have passed?

Comment: @ There is RaisedButton widget in Home.dart, when users click RaisedButton will call checkPoints() to check points and add points

Comment: you need to persist the data accross restarts, using shared_preference or hive

Comment: @AhmedKhattab, yes I think I have to save data but ,Can the user hack this function cus its on user side ?.

Comment: not in a single way possible @KhalifaAlkhatri

Comment: They could change the time setting in their phone. Use server side time